# Hyperledger Fabric: Peer Node Rollback

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following [Hyperledger V 1.4 documsation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peernode.html) to roll back the channel **mychannel** to block number **150** using this following command:

```
peer node rollback -c mychannel -b 150
```

If I run this inside CLI container it's showing:

> Validating the rollback parameters: ledgerID [mychannel], block number
> [0]
> **Error: ledgerID [mychannel] does not exist.**

If i run inside peer0 it is giving an error

> Error: as another peer node command is executing, wait for that
> command to complete its execution or terminate it before retrying:
> lock is already acquired on file
> /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/fileLock

I have tried different possible ways by stop and pausing the nodes but failed, can anyone please guide the right way to perform this task.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution as follow:

First network was up and running, I have added following command in docker compose file for required peer lets say peer0.org1.example.com,

```
command: peer node rollback -c mychannel -b 1 && peer node start
```

After saving the changes run following command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d  peer0.org1.example.com
```

Now remove rollback part from above command, I can see logs show that it has been rollback successfully.

```
docker logs peer0.org1.example.com
```

[image: docker logs]

Answer (score 0):

```
peer node rollback -c mychannel -b 150
```

Note: The above-said command  should be executed from the peer node, not from the CLI

```
Error: as another peer node command is executing, wait for that command to complete its execution or terminate it before retrying: lock is already acquired on file /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/fileLock
```

Please make sure that peer is offline when you are performing tasks such as

- peer node reset
- peer node rollback

Please note that rollback doest mean it delete the blocks permanently, after the rollback operation performed peer will receive blocks from the orderer or other peers

Comment: If I stop the peer node, I can't bash it, if node is running and I can't perform the operation, so how exactly to stop the node and rollback it. By the way from CLI container if I set environment variables for peer 1 , then it's the same , I can run peer node reset but not rollback from CLI, I can see the mychannel in the list , but don't know why it's showing "ledgerID [mychannel] does not exist"

Comment: Offline is doesn't mean you stop the container, make the peer away from the network, or disconnect it from the network. Even though you use the same peer MSP for CLI, the CLI process is different from the actual peer process. So please do not use CLI if you want to perform rollback then please don to use CLI